# sFlow display filters for source/destination ASN in wireshark

Tags: wireshark, wireshark-dissector

I have capture files containing sFlow data that I am trying to filter based on the "Extended gateway data" contained within.  The documentation at https://www.wireshark.org/docs/dfref/s/sflow.html shows a rich featureset of filters for reviewing the packets.

However, within Wireshark there are relatively few options to choose from when constructing a display filter:
[image: display filter screenshot]

Am I missing some basic usability concept?  For example "sflow.dstAS == 65000" results in a red bar/parser failure, but sflow.dstAS is documented in the URL above.